# Regex: \s is not matching \r\n

Tags: regex

It says "\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])"

reference: https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html & https://regex101.com

So, for a given regex:

```
<a>one statement\s*<\/a>
```

I expect the following result:

```
<a>one statement \r\n</a>            <- should match
<a>one statement \r\n  \n</a>        <- should match
<a>one statement      </a>           <- should match
<a>one statement .</a>               <- should not match
<a>one statement {anything else}</a> <- should not match
```

However, only the following statement matches (\s is matching only spaces)

```
<a>one statement      </a>
```

Did I understand something wrong? If yes, How can I achieve expected result?

**regex playground:** https://regex101.com/r/Pgiub4/1

Comment: From your playground link it seems that e.g. `\r` is literally part of the string, while the `\s` character class is concerned with _escape_ sequences. _if_ you want to match the literal backslash-plus-r you must further escape the backslash: `\\r`. cf. https://regex101.com/r/Pgiub4/2

Comment: the regex101 site doesn't interpolate \r to a white space return or \n to a whitespace newline.  So your example is incorrect!  Hope this helps

Comment: Per @Vorsprung's comment, you cannot simply paste `<a>one statement \r\n</a> ` as a string literal; you need to press the `Enter` key.

Comment: Ahh. got it. I used `<a>one statement(\s|\\r|\\n)*<\/a>` and it works. thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to parse the literal string (\r\n) and also handle new line and spaces, so I used:

```
<a>one statement(\s|\\r|\\n)*<\/a)
```

and it worked.

thanks to @jensgram and @MonkeyZeus for pointing it out!